# Creation of Vector array calling destructor in c++

Tags: c++, vector, destructor

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
class Students
{
    int *arr_roll;
public:
    Students (size_t a){
        arr_roll = new int(a);
    }
    ~Students(){
        std::cout<<"Destructor called"<<std::endl;
        //delete arr_roll;
    }
    int & operator [] (size_t t){
        return arr_roll[t];
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<Students> School(10,5);
    School[0][1] = 2;
    std::cout<< "School[0][1]: " << School[0][1]<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have a code like above and I am compiling it with gcc 9.5.0 .
The output I am getting is as follows

```
**Destructor called**
School[0][1]: 2
Destructor called
Destructor called
Destructor called
Destructor called
Destructor called
Destructor called
Destructor called
Destructor called
Destructor called
Destructor called
```

Can anybody please explain why the destructor is being called during the creation of the vector (The 1st print ** marked)

Comment: Add a copy constructor etc and all will be revealed. Also refer to [Rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: With `new int(a)` you create a *single* `int` value, and initializes it to `a`. You want `new int[a]` for an array.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Note prefer smart pointer over raw pointers that allocate memory using `new`

Comment: Equivalently, `std::vector<Students> School(10, Students(5));`. What do you think happens to the `Students` argument?

Comment: Oh and for arrays allocated with `new[]`, you need `delete[]`. Mismatching `new[]` and `delete` will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @OP see [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EPs51qGbx) with copy constructor. That should clear up things and the first comment.

Comment: none of the dupes is relevant for the quesiton. modlbnilo mentions the answer in their comment

Comment: I have to correct, among the many proposed duplicates there actually was 1 that was relevant here

Comment: Why are you not using :   std::vector<int> for arr_roll? That's going to prevent a lot of headaches and is what you should use in C++ anyway.  If you have to do this because your teacher tells you to, show him this [C++ core guidelines R.11 Avoid calling new and delete explicitly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly)

Comment: It's weird that you use a vector in `main`, but don't in `Student`. You should be using vectors everywhere, it will make your life much easier.

Comment: @john I dont think its the right duplicate. OP can remove all `new` and the member from the class and the question would remain the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```cpp
std::vector<Students> School(10,5);
```

You are invoking this overload of std::vector constructor:
[std::vector<T,Allocator>::vector - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

> ```cpp
> vector( size_type count,  
>                  const T& value,  
>                  const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
> ```

Since for `value` you've feed is `5` compiler performs implicit conversion to `Students` using your constructor:

```cpp
Students (size_t a)
```

So temporary automated object of type `Students` is created to pass it as argument `value` for `std::vector`.

After vector creation completes temporary object is destroyed.

You can:

- add `explicit` keyword to your constructor to prevent implicit conversions.
- use `emplace_back` to construct values directly inside a vector (loop is needed):

```cpp
std::vector<Students> School;
School.reserve(10);
for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i) {
    School.emplace_back(5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
std::vector<Students> School(10,5);
```

first creates an object of type `Students` using the **parameterized ctor** `Students(size_t)` and then uses the **implicitly generated copy constructor** `Students(const Students&)` to create `10` copies of that object. So there are total 11 objects constructed(1 using parameterized ctor and other using copy ctor).  Then at the time of `School`'s destruction, all elements are destructed using the destructor and we get the destructor called output.

This all happens because the ctor `(3)` given at [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) is used here:

> ```
> vector( size_type count,
>                 const T& value,
>                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );  (3) since c++11
> ```
>
> 3. **Constructs the container with `count` copies of elements with value value.**

---

You can verify this by adding a **user defined copy ctor** as done in [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ke6YMod9W).

---

Note that first the **parameterized ctor** `Students(size_t)` is **implicitly used** to create an object of `Students` type and then the copy ctor is used to create 10 copies.

Comment: Thanks for you reply and the Demo. If you count the number of ctor print and Destructor print in the Demo then you will find you will find ctor count is 10 and Destructor count is 11 .. this exactly  what I am not able to explain. The 1st Destructor is getting call at the line "std::vector<Students> School(10,5);" rest of 10 during the deallocation.

Comment: @DebabrataBardhan The first constructor is called when an object is constrcutred using the parameerized ctor `Students(size_t)`. You can verify this by adding a `cout` statement inside that ctor also. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ke6YMod9W) where I've added another cout and this should clear your doubts. Updated the demo in the answer also.

Comment: @DebabrataBardhan Check out the updated answer where I've explained why you get 11 destructors called. In particular, it is because first the parameterized ctor `Students(size_t)` is used to create an object and then other 10 copies of that object are made using the copy ctor. Thus, in total there are 11 objects(one created using parameterized ctor and other 10 created using copy ctor). Which is why you get 11 destructer calls.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a couple of issues unrelated to the additional output of the constructor your are asking about. Most issues removed, it boils down to this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

struct Students
{
    Students (size_t a){
    }
    ~Students(){
        std::cout<<"Destructor called"<<std::endl;
    }
};

void foo(const Students&) {}

int main(){
    foo(5); // 5 is implicitly converted to a Students instace
            // that instance is destroyed at the end of the expression
}
```

[Output is](https://godbolt.org/z/9GceecaPc):

```
Destructor called
```

In your case it is the call `std::vector<Students> School(10,5);` that constructs a temporary `Students` instance.

The big issue in your code is not to follow the rule of three. You shouldnt use raw `new`. Your constructor allocates a single integer, then `School[0][1]` accesses memory out of bounds. If you fix the constructor to allocate an array, then `//delete arr_roll;` in the destructor is wrong. Use `std::vector` or `std::array` to manage arrays for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was not real code but the code i tried preproduce a vector behavior that I was not able explain.  Why line "std::vector<Students> School(10,5);" calling the destructor just once  (the 1st print with **)  rest of the prints are explainable and correct.

Comment: Should be `void foo(const Students& )` to match `std::vector` behavior.

Comment: @DebabrataBardhan because you pass an `int` while the method takes a `const Student&` (fixed that in the meantime in my example), hence a temporary `Student` is constructed. And that will be destroyed after the call